# Default value for ipywidget.Dropdown() using VOILA Package

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, voila

I need to run my file.ipynb with VOILA package.

When I run this code, return this error, because the value is empty and after I select the values, run perfectly.

How can I set a default value on dropdown ?
Thanks

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

filename = 'data/sales_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
df.head()

df['Sales'] = df['Quantity Ordered'] * df['Price Each']

    wid_city = widgets.Dropdown(name='city')
wid_city.options = list(df.City.unique())

wid_product = widgets.Dropdown(name='product')
wid_product.options = list(df.Product.unique())

def func (city, product):
    df_tmp = df[df['City']==wid_city.value].copy()
    df_tmp = df_tmp[df_tmp['Product']==wid_product.value]
    
    ax = df_tmp.groupby(['Month']).sum()['Sales'].plot.bar()
    plt.ylabel('Sales ($)')
    plt.xlabel('Month')
    plt.show()
    
interactive_plot = widgets.interactive(func, city=wid_city, product=wid_product)

output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '500px'

interactive_plot
```

Comment: It seems to work when I use JupyterLab. I'm using the data [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/2be7cecb3807033d036b8af7d9dcbcba) since you didn't include data. (Always make a minimal reproducible example to share as it makes this much easier.) You should be able to test that part by clicking [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb) to launch an active session via MyBinder. Packages are installed. You just need to add the CSV file and your code to a new notebook. ...

Comment: <continued> Start with trying it with the data I provided and then your CSV file. My thinking is that would help maybe it isn't the code but the data file?

Comment: I just checked and it runs in Voila there too. You can switch to that mode by using the symbol at the top of the notebook. It is the icon on the tool bar that has the yellow squiggle over the green line. I quickly sent what I was finding because I'm heading out soon.